# Prove $D^{\alpha}f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to prove this following theorem, but I haven't been able to come up with a proof.

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\Delta f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then $D^{\alpha}f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ where $|\alpha|\leq 2$

Comment: For all multiindices $\alpha$?

Comment: @md2perpe For a generic $\alpha$, unknown.

Comment: You must be leaving something out. If $|\alpha|>2$ this is obvious nonsense. For $|\alpha|\le 2$ it's easy using the Fourier transform

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're right, $|\alpha|\leq 2$, but could you explain how is it "easy"? It doesn't seem obvious at all

Comment: Well, what is $||D^\alpha f||_2$, in terms of $\hat f$?